# email-program (Thunderbird) that calls a ps-script with the email text (and attachements)

Tags: email, powershell

the (Linux) KDE-email program has the option to call a perl script with the text and/or the attachement (arguments of this call).

I was looking whether Thunderbird can do this as well: call a powershell script with the emailt-text (and attachements) if a filter is triggered.

I couldn't find anything?

Does anybody has a suggestion for an Windows-Email-Program that supports this - or do I have to write a script that looks at the email-provider for emails to be treated by that script?

Thanks in advance,
Gooly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's not Thunderbird, but Outlook has some pretty powerful email rules that can run scripts, exe's, etc. when specific emails come in.

Here is an example of being able to execute PowerShell scripts from email based on a rule: [Execute PowerShell Scripts from Your Smartphone](http://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2008/05/08/execute-powershell-scripts-from-your-smartphone/)

The only way that I can think of using Thunderbird to do the same thing is to use an extension because the feature is not native. For ex you could try: [FiltaQuilla](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/filtaquilla/)

Comment: I tried FiltaQuilla I can define a filter but I cannot enter any command like "powershell -file myScript ...". Outlook might be an option. Thank you!

Comment: What you may have to do is put the "powershell -file myScript ..." inside a batch .cmd file, so it is a single thing that is executed, and pull out the arguments from that.

Comment: hmm? I do have to enter somewhere the name of the filename that has to be executed. If I don't have the option in that addon to enter this filename the addon cannot execute it automatically if a new email in e.g. a specific folder arrives. Why do I have a computer if at the end I have to do it myself ;)